# how to add favicon in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I want to add a favicon in joomla 1.5.12 package. I'm using rockettheme rt_catalyst

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

1. Drop a `favicon.ico` file into your site's root directory (i.e example.com/favicon.ico)
2. Add `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/path/to/your/icon.extension" />` within your theme's `head` block.